# instantiate an object or a list of objects with variables

Tags: c#

Let s assume that i have a string named str with some value that is the name of a class.
e.g  `string str="MyClass";` Is it any way to instatiate an object or a list of objects using this variable?

( That's because I don't know from the beginning what type of objects i should create but somewhere inside the program I get a list of strings with the name of the classes )

Some dummy silly code of what i really want is :

```
List<**str**> myList = new List<str>();
```

or

```
**str** object = new **str**();
```

Thanx in advance!

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to do this.  It can be done, but it virtually never should be.  Chances are there's a better way for you to address what the true underlying problem is.

Comment: With @Servy. Just let your objects implement an interface or inherit from a base class and declare the list as List<InterfaceOrBaseClass>.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection, assume your class is in the same assembly:

```
string input = "MyClass";

var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                   .GetTypes()
                   .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == input);

MyClass myObject = (MyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.However in this case (3rd statement) you have to write again explicitly the name of the class and cast with the name of the class(MyClass) as if you knew what class you have to use.But I do not know the name from start.I only get a string in the middle of the program that is related to a class name.

Comment: @Cuong Le: we could change the 3rd statement to: dynamic myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type); as dynamic type was designed for this purpose.

Comment: Or it's better to use a base class of MyClass in this case. Because it makes no sense to use reflection when we know the type in advance: BaseClass myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as BaseClass;

Answer (score 0):

You could base your code on the following, which constructs an instance of MyClass given its name:

```
namespace MyNameSpace {

    public class MyClass {
        public MyClass() {
            // initialise
        }

        public static MyClass CreateMyClassFromName() {
            Type myType = Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.MyClass");
            System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constinfo = myType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
            MyClass mc = (MyClass)constinfo.Invoke(null);
            return mc;
        }

    }

}
```